# Unity 3D Android KeyStore Tampered with

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore, android-keystore

Error 1 :

> Error: Unable to read 'C:\Users\Derrick\Desktop\MyKeystore.keystore'
>
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Error 2 :

> Error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
>
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Error 3 :

> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for details.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Derrick/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

```
stderr[
Error: Unable to read 'C:\Users\Derrick\Desktop\MyKeystore.keystore'
Error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
]
stdout[

]
```